# Java Stream- Add two columns and sum results

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Price object that has two attributes, cost and tax.  I want to be able to stream over a list of Price Objects, add the cost and tax together, and then sum up the total.

Is there a way to do this entirely in a Java 8 stream?  I am thinking of logic along the lines of this:

```
    List<Price> prices = Price.find.all();
    Double sum = 0.0;
    prices.stream().forEach(price -> { sum = sum + price.cost + price.tax });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double total = prices.stream()
                     .mapToDouble(price -> price.cost + price.tax)
                     .sum();
```

As simple as that.